# Using a DrawerLayout without navigation functionality

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I have been looking into `DrawerLayout` for my project's slideout menu. It seems to behave the way I want, except for one thing.

I've run a few sample projects and they all seem to have one thing in common: the `DrawerLayout` is always the main part of the application, as in:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Where `activity_main` is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Also, `DrawerLayout` seems to have strong ties to navigation, where it's used to jump between fragments.

My problem is, I do not wish to use this slideout menu for navigation, nor do I have any desire to make my app's current main page a `Fragment`. I want a slideout menu, but I will be using it for settings mostly, not to move around the app.

Is there any way to have a simple slideout menu, which behaves visually and tactically like `DrawerLayout`, but without the need to have all my views set as fragments of it?

Comment: I think you can create custom view with slide in, slide out animation. Using the coordinator layout and anchor property.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by your statement "nor do I have any desire to make my app's current main page a Fragment". Why do you think you'd have to do that?

Comment: `DrawerLayout` is just a regular ol' `ViewGroup`. It's not inherently tied to navigation or `Fragment`s. If you want a settings drawer, then `DrawerLayout` is perfectly fine for that. The main content can be pretty much any `View` you want. It doesn't have to be a `Fragment`, or a holder for one. Similarly, the drawer can be pretty much any `View` you want, as well. It doesn't have to be a `NavigationView`. Just make sure the drawer `View` has the `layout_gravity` attribute, its `layout_width` is set appropriately, and that it's listed last within the `DrawerLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done this using 1. a custom RelativeLayout class with a ViewTreeObserver referencing a custom X or Y property (for drawer you would use X) 2. objectAnimator XML referencing same custom property 3. Fragment class for the UI itself, using the custom Layout class 4. use `setCustomAnimations` method of `getFragmentManager` to show / hide the menu.

Here's an example, just change it to horizontal

[Fragment Translation Animation for a Menu](http://trickyandroid.com/fragments-translate-animation/)